# Unable to use multiple attributes within .select() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I've written a script in python to get the different links to the different posts from a website. I can get the desired output if I choose any single attribute like `a[href^='/questions/']` or `.question-hyperlink`.

> ***My question is: how can I use two attributes from the same node within the `.select()` method like I've tried below?***

My attempt so far (produces no result; no error either):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
for item in soup.select("a[href^='/questions/'].question-hyperlink"):
    print(item.get("href"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your code works fine. I'm getting your expected results. I just had to pip install lxml and BeautifulSoup4 to run it.

```
/questions/54035304/unable-to-use-multiple-attributes-within-select-method
/questions/54035268/div-returns-empty-while-scraping-price-using-beautifulsoup-everything-else-lik
/questions/54035199/scrapy-restart-scrapoxy-instances
/questions/54034484/how-i-can-read-multiple-web-addresses-with-sign-in-address-that-block-dynami
```

P.S. You need to use last `lxml` and `bs4` versions. So you might need to execute

- `pip3 install lxml --upgrade`
- `pip3 install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade`

Comment: Can you share how you defined your `BeautifulSoup` instance?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to @robots.txt code.

    `import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for item in soup.select("a[href^='/questions/'].question-hyperlink"):
    print(item.get("href"))`

Comment: AFAIK, yes you need `lxml` to be installed to be able to use `lxml` parser, but I still see no results even with `lxml` installed... Can you share bs4, lxml, Python versions?

Comment: Python 3.6, bs4 4.7.0, lxml 4.2.6

Comment: Try above versions which I have used. I'm not sure whats stopping your code to produce the results

Comment: Yep, after upgrades with this set Python 3.6, bs4 4.7.0, lxml 4.2.6 works... I guess that was some kind of incompatibility issue

Comment: I reran after upgrdation and find it working now @Sabesh Rajendran.

Comment: Have you noticed @sir Andersson that this upgradation also supports pseudo-selectors?

Comment: @robots.txt , What do you mean by *pseudo-selectors*? I didn't check yet

Comment: This is what I meant `item = soup.select_one(".question-hyperlink:contains('Unable to use')").text : print(item)` @sir Andersson.

Comment: @robots.txt , oh, yeah. That was available in previous `lxml` versions also